# kdb ticker plant: where to find documentation on .u.upd?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I am aware of [this resource](https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/d/tick.htm). But it does not spell out what parameters `.u.upd` takes and how to check if it worked.

This statement executes without error, although it does not seem to do anything:

```
.u.upd[`t;(`$"abc";1;2;3)]
```

If I define the table beforehand, e.g.

```
t:([] name:"aaa";a:1;b:2;c:3)
```

then the above `.u.upd` still runs without error, and does not change `t`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.u.upd` has the same function signature as `insert` (see http://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/#insert) in prefix form. In the most simplest case, `.u.upd` may get defined as `insert`.

so:
`` .u.upd[`table;<records>] ``

For example:

```
q).u.upd:insert
q)show tbl:([] a:`x`y;b:10 20)
   a b
   ----
   x 10
   y 20
q).u.upd[`tbl;(`z;30)]
   ,2
q)show tbl
   a b
   ----
   x 10
   y 20
   z 30
q).u.upd[`tbl;(`a`b`c;1 2 3)]
   3 4 5
q)show tbl
   a b
   ----
   x 10
   y 20
   z 30
   a 1
   b 2
   c 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Documentation including the event sequence, connection diagram etc. for tickerplants can be found here:
http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/kdb-tick-data-store

[image]

> **.u.upd[tableName; tableData]** accepts two arguments, for inserting data
>   to a named table. This function will normally be called from a
>   feedhandler. It takes the tableData, adds a time column if one is
>   present, inserts it into the in-memory table, appends to the log file
>   and finally increases the log file counter.